# Pulumi import existing Azure ResourceGroup to Azure Core

Tags: azure, pulumi, pulumi-azure

We have a Resource Group in Azure. We created this resource using the following code:

```
 private Pulumi.Azure.Core.ResourceGroup CreateResourceGroup(string resourceGroupName)
    {
        return new Pulumi.Azure.Core.ResourceGroup(resourceGroupName,
            new Pulumi.Azure.Core.ResourceGroupArgs
            {
                Name = resourceGroupName,
                Location = "westeurope"
            });
    }
CreateResourceGroup("rg-magic-apps");
```

Now we need to import this structure to a completely new stack (the old stack is NOT available anymore) so our only way is to import that resourcegroup.

Following the pulumi documentation we tried

```
pulumi import azure:core/resourceGroup:ResourceGroup /subscriptions/{subscriptionid}/resourceGroups/rg-magic-apps
```

but received

> error: an inline resource must be specified if no import file is used

Is there a parameter missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the name of the resource group before the subscription.

```
pulumi import azure:core/resourceGroup:ResourceGroup rg-magic-apps /subscriptions/{subscriptionid}/resourceGroups/rg-magic-apps
```